# JQuery plugins stop working on appending querystring parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new with Javascript programming, I need to insert this code in the body of a page, I take some Get parameters from URL and I attach them to the iframe string:

```
<script>
document.write("<iframe width='700' height='500' frameborder='0' src=https://www.mysite.com/abs/indexabs.php?stid=261&lg=en&step2=1&"+unescape(window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1)))+"></iframe>"
</script>
```

This code runs and loads the iframe content...but there are other jQuery elements on the page, that don't run anymore (i.e. Nivo slider, Jquery UI datepicker)

Is  there a different manner to do the same without jQuery incompatibility?

Thanks

Comment: its more likely an error in your code then js/jquery incompatibility. can we have a jsbin/jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry, now you can see the code. This the URL with problem in Nivo and Datepicker: http://www.hotelkennedy.org/demo/booking.htm - the same page without the script is OK here: http://www.hotelkennedy.org/demo/booking2.htm